# How to change the double click option in the Xtrascheduler

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using devxpress xtra scheduler.In the xtrascheduler i disabled the default context menu and i created a new context menu and it is working.But the problem is when i double click on the scheduler the existing appointment form is opening..But i need to open the form that i have added.How it can be done>??please help me...

Answer (score 0):

To learn how this can be done, please refer to the

[How to: Create a Custom EditAppointment Form with Custom Fields](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2288)

Also, the XtraScheduler's Demo application shows how this can be done in the Customization-->Custom Appointment Form module.